# Library to modify PHP code

Tags: library, php

I am looking for a library that allows me to modify PHP code, e.g.

- delete/rename all functions/methods with a specific name across multiple files
- programmatically change visibility of methods
- change string delimiters from `"` to `'` and vice-versa
- etc.

Some language other that PHP (Python would be great...) would be preferred, but I am pretty much language-agnostic.

Comment: Which IDE do you use (and can't it already do all of that? #1 sounds like global search/replace #3 sounds like refactoring #2 sounds like manually changing public/private/protected)

Comment: 1.) I am mostly using Emacs and no IDE, 2.) It's not simply a search/replace as the library needs to know about the structural context (e.g. I might only care about renaming methods and not functions/ I might only want to change visibility of methods and not of object variables, ...), so static analysis is required.

In the meantime I found the library https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser though which parses the code, lets me walk/manipulate the AST and provides a pretty printer for transforming the AST back into code. Just wished it was written in a language other than PHP...

Comment: I cannot stress strongly enough how important a debugger is - set breakpoints, run until one is hit, examine the call stack & variables, etc, etc. It is your best friend as a developer. The easiest way to get one is to use an IDE. [PhpStor](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) is excellent, but not free. I  have also had great success with [EclipsePdt](https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) and [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/features/php/). Others are others. You are holding yourself back terribly by not using one. A decent IDE will have support for refactoring, which will handle most of your requests

Comment: I am well aware of IDEs but consciously chose not to use one for most of my work. The downsides outweigh the positives for me by quite a margin and would make me less productive overall. Besides, you can easily interface to a debugger from within Emacs if you chose to do so. As for refactoring there are a couple things that an IDE supports better I suppose, but I am quite certain it can't do the static analysis I need for the most part. If I really need to make use of refactoring features I can always just start up Eclipse (but that happens quite rarely...)

Comment: It seems that I can't help you, but I wish you welcome and good luck. I hope that you get an answer